# I need to place VS SSDT and VS in a single place, I have them separated

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I installed VS SSDT first, and later for some requirement I installed VS, the thing is that they are different installations and I want them in a single one.

What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) instructions

[image: Microsoft Instructions]